# Printing out strings to align to match it's placement in another String

Tags: java

I need to print out strings that align to match it's placement in another String when data is grouped together. For instance:

I have an ArrayList of Strings containing:

```
[0]    "data1 data2 data3"
[1]    "data1 data2 data3"
[2]    "data3"
[3]    "data4"
[4]    "data4 data5"
```

I want the output to be

```
[0]    "data1 data2 data3"
[1]    "data1 data2 data3"
[2]    "            data3"
[3]    "data4"
[4]    "data4 data5"
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Also, the question is unclear. Why is data4 allowed to be below data1? Because [2] has no data1?

Comment: make the data multi-dimensional

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could achieve your desired result using a `java.util.HashMap` to get the maximum indices of tokens in the strings. How you want to break the strings into tokens is not clear in your question, so I've notated that section in the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("data1 data2 data3",
        "data1 data2 data3", "data3", "data4", "data4 data5");
    List<String[]> tokens = new ArrayList<String[]>(strings.size());
    for (String s: strings) {
        tokens.add(s.split(" ")); // customize tokenization to your needs
    }
    Map<String, Integer> maxIndices = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
        int index = -1;
        for (String t: tokens.get(i)) {
            index = strings.get(i).indexOf(t, index + 1);
            Integer maxIndex = maxIndices.get(t);
            if (maxIndex == null || maxIndex.intValue() < index) {
                maxIndices.put(t, Integer.valueOf(index));
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
        int index = -1;
        for (String t: tokens.get(i)) {
            index = strings.get(i).indexOf(t, index + 1);
            int maxIndex = maxIndices.get(t).intValue();
            if (index < maxIndex) {
                char[] padding = new char[maxIndex - index];
                Arrays.fill(padding, ' ');
                strings.set(i, strings.get(i).substring(0, index)
                    + new String(padding) + strings.get(i).substring(index));
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(i); System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(strings.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (assuming that strings that didn't occur before are left unaligned). Using *org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils*

```
// your list
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

//populate with data
list.add("data1 data2 data3");
list.add("data1 data2 data3");
list.add("data3");
list.add("data4");
list.add("data4 data5");
list.add("data3");
list.add("data2 data3");
```

//print output

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   int pos = findPosition(list.get(i), i);
   System.out.println(StringUtils.leftPad(list.get(i),
   pos + list.get(i).length(), " "));
}
```

//find position in previous strings

```
int findPosition(String string, int index) {

    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        pos = list.get(i).indexOf(string);
        if (pos != -1)
            return pos;
    }
    return pos;
}
```